# How can I express the average value of an unknown function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that the amount of drug in a patient's body is governed by

$$M'(t) = a(t) - C_L(t)C(t)\>, M(0) = 0\>.$$

Here, $a$ is the uptake rate, $C_L$ is the clearance rate, and $C$ is the concentration.

My book says I can express the average clearance rate as

$$ \overline{C_L} = \dfrac{\int_0^\infty a(t)\, dt}{\int_0^\infty C(t)\, dt}$$

but I am now quite sure how to arrive at that.  The average value of a function over the interval $[a,b]$ is

$$ \dfrac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(t)\,dt \>.$$

How can I derive $\overline{C_L}$?

Comment: @Harry49 The book is 'Computational Pharmacokinetics' by Anders Källén

Comment: @Harry49 page 2, if you a really interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not *clear* how this is obtained. It may not make sense in pharmacokinetics, but it follows from $M(\infty) = 0$. Indeed, integrating the time-derivative of the amount of drug $M'(t)$ over $[0,\infty]$, one has
$$
0 = M(\infty) - M(0) = \int_0^\infty a(t)\,\mathrm{d}t - \int_0^\infty C_L(t)\, C(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \, .
$$
The average $\overline{C_L}$ of a function $C_L$ over some interval $\Omega$ is defined as the constant function which has the same integral as $C_L$ over $\Omega$. Understanding this definition as "$\overline{C_L}$ is the constant equivalent clearance over $\Omega = [0,\infty]$", we get the identity
$$
\int_0^\infty C_L(t)\, C(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \overline{C_L} \int_0^\infty C(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \, ,
$$
which gives the definition of your book.

Comment: No, it isn't clear at all.  But I think this is the right interpretation, and is something I had realized shortly after asking the question.  Thanks.